# Changing document's attributes in Python's xml.dom.minidom

Tags: python, xml

I created a `xml.dom.minidom.Document`.

How do I give it attributes so that when I do `.toprettyxml()` it will show like this:

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-2"?>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.toprettyxml()` has an encoding keyword argument:

```
Document.toprettyxml(self, indent='\t', newl='\n', encoding=None)
```